# Is a single config object a bad idea?

Tags: configuration

In most of my applications, I have a singleton or static "config" object, in charge of reading various settings from disk. Almost all classes use it, for various purposes. Essentially it's just a hash table of name/value pairs. It's read-only, so I haven't been too concerned with the fact that I have so much global state. But now that I'm getting started with unit testing, it's starting to become an issue.

One problem is that you don't usually want to test with the same configuration that you run with. There are a couple of solutions to this:

- Give the config object a setter that's ONLY used for testing, so you can pass in different settings.
- Continue using a single config object, but change it from a singleton to an instance that you pass around everywhere it's needed. Then you can construct it once in your application, and once in your tests, with different settings.

But either way, you're still left with a second problem: almost any class can use the config object. So in a test, you need to set up the configuration for the class being tested, but also ALL of its dependencies. This can make your testing code ugly.

I'm starting to come to the conclusion that this kind of config object is a bad idea. What do you think? What are some alternatives? And how do you start refactoring an application that uses configuration everywhere?

Comment: The config gets its settings by reading a file on disk, right? So why not just have a "test.config" file that it can read?

Comment: That solves the first problem, but not the second.

Comment: @JW01: Do all your tests need a markedly different configuration, then? You're going to have to set up that configuration *somewhere* during your test, aren't you?

Comment: True. But if I continue using a single pool of settings (with a different pool for testing), then all my tests end up using the same settings. And since I may want to test the behavior with different settings, this isn't ideal.

Comment: "So in a test, you need to set up the configuration for the class being tested, but also ALL of its dependencies. This can make your testing code ugly." Have an example? I have a feeling that it's not the structure of your whole application connecting to the config class but rather the structure of the config class itself that is making things "ugly". Shouldn't setting up the configuration of a class automatically configure its dependencies?

Comment: @JW01: How would not using a config object help, in that case?

Comment: @AndrewKS: My config class is essentially a big pool of name-value pairs. Any class can use any of them. So when you construct an object X, it might construct an object Y that reads its own config settings. Right now, you can set up the config object with X's settings but not Y's. Obviously this is a problem, but it seems inevitable if everyone can read from the same config object.

Comment: @JW01: How would you set the other dependencies into "test configuration" if you didn't have the config object?

Comment: @Anon: I guess the problem is that when I construct an object, I don't *know* which config settings all its dependencies use. If they were individual parameters, this would be more clear, and I could require them in the constructor. But since the config object is essentially a big hashmap, I can't see which settings are used by which classes.

Comment: @JW01: Do you *really* want a constructor that looks like `Foo::Foo(int someArg, bool config1, bool config2, float config3, int config4, ConfigParam config5, BazFactory config6, FooBarAbstractFactoryFactory config7, bool config8, FrobManager config9, BarCallback config10...`

Comment: Well, no. But there are alternatives: combining multiple settings into objects, or using default values for some settings, with setter methods to override them. I agree that a single config object gives you a lot of convenience; that's why I've been using it all along. My purpose for asking this question was to think about whether it's worth the tradeoffs.

Comment: @JW01: The answer I gave lets you move from the single static config object you have now to the segmented interfaces and provides a hook for testability from day 1.  It provides the convenience of a static access point and the ability to provide alternate implementations.  I mention it because it seems to have been somewhat overlooked.  YMMV.

Answer (score 43):

I don't have a problem with a single config object, and can see the advantage in keeping all settings in one place.

However, using that single object everywhere will result in a high level of coupling between the config object and the classes that use it. If you need to change the config class you may have to visit every instance in which it is used and check that you haven't broken anything.

One way to deal with this is to create multiple interfaces that expose parts of the config  object that are needed by different parts of the app. Rather than allowing other classes to access the config object, you pass instances of an interface to the classes that need it. That way, the parts of the app that use config depend on the smaller collection of fields in the interface rather than the whole config class. Finally, for unit testing you can create a custom class that implements the interface.

If you want to explore these ideas further, I recommend reading about [SOLID](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod) [principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29), particularly the [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) and the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle).

Answer (score 8):

I segregate groups of related settings with interfaces.

Something like:

```
public interface INotificationEmailSettings {
   public string To { get; set; }
}

public interface IMediaFileSettings {
    public string BasePath { get; set; }
}
```

etc.

Now, for a real environment, a single class will implement many of these interfaces.  That class may pull from a DB or the app config or what have you, but often it knows how to get most of the settings.

But segregating by interface makes the actual dependencies much more explicit and fine grained, and this is an obvious improvement for testability.

But .. I don't always want to be forced to inject or provide the settings as a dependency.  There's an argument that could be made that I should, for consistency or explicitness.  But in real life it seems an unnecessary restriction.

So, I'll use a static class as a facade, providing easy entry from anywhere to settings, and within that static class I will service locate the implementation of the interface and get the setting.

I know service location gets a quick thumbs down from most, but let's face it, providing a dependency through a constructor is a weight, and sometimes that weight is more than I care to bear.  Service Location is the solution to maintaining testability through programming to interfaces and allowing multiple implementations while still providing the convenience (in carefully measured and appropriately few situations) of a static singleton entry point.

```
public static class AllSettings {
    public INotificationEmailSettings NotificationEmailSettings {
        get {
            return ServiceLocator.Get<INotificationEmailSettings>();
        }
    }
}
```

I find this mix to be the best of all worlds.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, as you realized, a global config object makes unit testing hard. Having a "secret" setter for unit testing is a quick hack, which although not nice, can be very useful: it enables you to start writing unit tests, so that you can refactor your code towards a better design over time.

(Obligatory reference: [Working Effectively With Legacy Code](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131177052). It contains this and many more invaluable tricks for unit testing legacy code.)

In my experience, the best is to have as little dependencies on global config as possible. Which is not necessarily zero though - it all depends on the circumstances. Having a few high level "organizer" classes which access the global config and pass on the actual config properties to the objects they create and use can work well, as long as the organizers do only that, e.g. do not contain much testable code themselves. This allows you to test most or all of the unit testable important functionality of the app, while still not completely disrupting the existing physical configuration schema.

This is already getting close to a genuine dependency injection solution though, like Spring for Java. If you can migrate to such a framework, fine. But in real life, and especially when dealing with a legacy app, often the slow and meticulous refactoring towards DI is the best achievable compromise.

Comment: I've really liked your approach and I wouldn't suggest that the idea of a setter should be kept "secret" or considered a "quick hack" for that matter. If you embrace the stance that unit tests are an important user/consumer/part of your application, then having `test_` attributes and methods isn't such a bad thing anymore, right? I do agree that the genuine solution to the problem is to employ a DI framework, but in examples like yours, when working with legacy code, or other simple cases, not alienating test code applies cleanly.

Comment: @kRON, these are immensely useful and practical tricks for making legacy code unit testable, and I am using them extensively as well. However, ideally the production code should not contain any features introduced solely for the purpose of testing. In the long run, this is where I am refactoring towards.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, in the Java world, this is what Spring is meant for. It creates and manages objects (beans) based on certain properties that are set at runtime, and is otherwise transparent to your application. You can go with the test.config file that Anon. mentions or you can include some logic in the config file that Spring will handle to set properties based on some other key (e.g. hostname or environment).

As regards your second problem, you can get around that by some rearchitecture but it's not as severe as it seems. What this means in your case is that you wouldn't, for example, have a global Config object that various other classes use. You'd just configure those other classes through Spring and then have no config object because everything that needed configuration got it through Spring, so you can use those classes directly in your code.

Answer (score 2):

This question is really about a more general issue than configuration.  As soon as I read the word "singleton" I immediately thought of all the problems associated with that pattern, not least of which is poor testability.

The Singleton pattern is "considered harmful".  Meaning, it's not *always* the wrong thing, but it *usually* is.  If you're ever considering using a singleton pattern for *anything*, stop to consider:

- Will you ever need to subclass it?
- Will you ever need to program to an interface?
- Do you need to run unit tests against it?
- Will you need to modify it frequently?
- Is your application intended to support multiple production platforms/environments?
- Are you even a little concerned about memory usage?

If your answer is "yes" to any of these (and probably several other things I didn't think of), then you probably don't want to use a singleton.  Configurations often need a great deal more flexibility than a singleton (or for that matter, any instanceless class) can provide.

If you want almost all the benefits of a singleton without any of the pain, then use a dependency injection framework like Spring or Castle or whatever is available for your environment.  That way you only ever have to declare it once and the container will automatically provide an instance to whatever needs it.

Answer (score 0):

One way I have handled this in C# is to have a singleton object that locks during instance creation and initializes all data at once for use by all client objects.  If this singleton can handle key/values pairs, you could store any manner of data including complex keys for use by many different clients and client types.  If you want to keep it dynamic and load new client data as needed, you could verify the existence of a client main key and, if missing, load the data for that client, appending it to the main dictionary.  It is also possible that the primary config singleton could contain sets of client data where multiples of the same client type use the same data all accessed via the primary config singleton.  Much of this config object organization may depend on how your config clients need to access this information and whether that information is static or dynamic.  I have used both key/value configs as well as specific object APIs depending upon which was needed.

One of my config singletons can receive messages to reload from a database.  In this case, I load into a second object collection and only lock the main collection in order to swap collections.  This prevents blocking reads on other threads.

If loading from config files, you could have a file hierarchy.  Settings in one file can specify which of the other files to load.  I have used this mechanism with C# Windows services that have multiple, optional components, each with their own config settings.  The file structure patterns were the same across files, but were loaded or not based on the primary file settings.

Answer (score 0):

The class you're describing is sounding like a [God object antipattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) except with data instead of functions.  That is a problem. You should probably have the config data read and stored in the appropriate object while only reading the data again if it is needed for some reason.

Additionally you're using a Singleton for a reason which is not appropriate.  Singletons should only be used when the existence of multiple objects will create a bad state.  Using a Singleton in this case is inappropriate as having more than one of a configuration reader should not cause an error state right away.  If you have more than one, you're probably doing it wrong, but it's not absolutely necessary that you only have one of a configuration reader.

Finally, creating such a global state is a violation of encapsulation as you're allowing more classes than need to know access the data directly.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if there are a lot of settings, with "clumps" of related ones, it makes sense to split those up into separate interfaces with respective implementations - then inject those interfaces where needed with DI. You gain testability, lower coupling, and SRP.

I was inspired on this matter by Joshua Flanagan of Los Techies; [he wrote an article](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/joshuaflanagan/archive/2009/07/12/how-we-handle-application-configuration.aspx) on the matter some time ago.

Answer (score -1):

I am having a hard time understanding what the fuzz is about. You typically pass a resource identifier to your application at startup that tells it what configuration to load. This could be a file path. The way you access your configuration data from within your application is hardly relevant.

You may want to consider having separate stores for application level configuration, machine level configuration and user level configuration. But this may not be useful for your kind of application.

Comment: That's a valid question to ask - why would one have complicated thoughts about config when it comes from one resource?

One answer is, it often doesn't. Application configuration can depend on environment variables, commandline switches, multiple config files and stuff in the database. Precendence and relevance of these sources might be different for each part of the app, especially if it is designed for plugins, events or addon modules which may provide their own config options and config sources.